# simplify $3n - 3 * 2^{\log _{3}(n)}$

Tags: logarithms

How can I simplify this so I don't have a log in the exponent ?
$3n - 3 * 2^{\log _{3}(n)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $3n - 3 * 2^{\log _{3}(n)} = y $

'Exponentiate' both sides by 3,

You end up with $ 3^y = \frac {3^{3n}}{3^{(3)(2)^{\log _{3}(n)}}}$

Can you go from there?

Going further,

$ 3^y = \frac {3^{3n}}{3^{(3)(3^{ \log_3 (2) \log_3 (n))}}} = \frac {3^{3n}}{3^{3n^{ \log_3 (2)}}}$

$ \ln(3^y) = 3n \ln(3) - 3n^{ \log_3 (2)} ln(3) = y \ln(3)$

$ y = 3n - 3n^{ \log_3 (2)}$

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Your calculation contains a mistake: $(3)(2)^{\log_{3}(n)} = \log_{3}(n^6)$ (which is $(3)(2){\log_{3}(n)}$) is true if and only if $n \in \{3, 9\}$.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it, it became a more complicated version of your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help: $2 = 3^{\log_{3}(2)}$, and so $2^{\log _{3}(n)} = 3^{\log_{3}(2)\log_{3}(n)} = n^{\log_{3}(2)}$, so in total:

$$
3n - 3 \cdot 2^{\log _{3}(n)} = 3n - 3n^{\log_{3}(2)}
$$